# Asp.Net Button click Event inside Repeater inside UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, updatepanel, repeater

I am trying to use a Repeater inside a Updatepanel and have Buttons that delete one entery in the Database and get the new Data for the Repeater and Update the Panel. I have tried a LinkButton, but it does always postback and the page relodes. Then i tried a regular Button and create a Event for that Button on DataBound Event. But it doesnt work. Here is the code:

aspx file:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="Panel">
        <ContentTemplate> 
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="saveTable">
                <tr style="font-weight: bold;">
                    <td>Erstellt am</td>
                    <td>Anforderer</td>
                    <td>Werk</td>
                    <td>Gebäude</td>
                    <td>Start Datum</td>

                    <td>Löschen</td>
                    <td>Benutzen</td>
                </tr> 


            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" onitemdatabound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
                <ItemTemplate>

                <tr id="Meldung<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"meldungId")%>">
                    <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "timestamp").ToString().Substring(0, 10)%></td>
                    <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"nameAnforderer") %></td>
                    <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Werk") %></td>
                    <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Building") %></td>
                    <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"startDatum").ToString().Substring(0, 10) %></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="test"/>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

               </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            </table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and in the code behind i give the Button with id = test a event

```
    protected void deleteMeldung(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }

    protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object source, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
        RepeaterItem repeaterSource = e.Item;
        Button btn1 = repeaterSource.FindControl("test") as Button;
        DataRowView drv = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
        string meldungId = drv.Row["meldungId"].ToString();

        btn1.ID = "myNewButton"+meldungId;
        btn1.Click += new EventHandler(deleteMeldung);
        btn1.Text = "delete";

    }
```

so whats working is passing the Text and the ID to each button like that. But the Buttons do not have the Click Event to call deleteMeldung()

Comment: you can use:   <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Repeater1" EventName="youronclickevent" />
                </Triggers>
so it will be not reload your page.. with this you can use linkbutton..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I tend to do is to have a separate delete button outside of the repeater (this is usually asp:Button with style set to 'display:none' along with a hidden field. Lets call these B_Delete and HF_DeleteId.

The buttons inside of the repeater do not cause postback themselves, but they only set the ID of the given row to the hidden field HF_DeleteId, and then call $('#B_Delete').click() (where the B_Delete should be replaced with current ClientID of the button). Then in the server method B_Delete_Click you can retrieve the ID of the row to be deleted from the hidden field. Works with update panels no problem. No need to mess with triggers and handling events from dynamically generated buttons.

It may look like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UP_Rptr" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RPTR_DeleteTest" EnableViewState="False" OnItemDataBound="RPTR_DeleteTest_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div>
                    <span><%# Eval("ID") %></span>
                    <span><%# Eval("Name") %></span>
                    <span><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LB_Delete" Text="delete"></asp:LinkButton></span>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HF_DeleteId" />        
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="B_Delete" OnClick="B_Delete_Click" Style="display:none;" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And the server methods:

```
protected void RPTR_DeleteTest_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   var lb = e.Item.Controls[1] as LinkButton; // for simplicity only - do not use code like this
   lb.OnClientClick = String.Format("$('#{0}').val('{1}');$('#{2}').click();return false;",                                         
                 HF_DeleteId.ClientID, 
                 DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "ID"),
                 B_Delete.ClientID);
}

protected void B_Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id = Int32.Parse(HF_DeleteId.Value);
    // do your sanity checks and deletion logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried Pafkas solution and it worked, thank you for that. However, i was intressted if there is any other way to solve this problem and i found another solution, i registred every LinkButton with the ScriptManager like that:

```
        btn1.Click += new EventHandler((sender1, e1) => deleteMeldung(sender1, e1, meldungId));

        ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);
        if (scriptManager != null) {
            scriptManager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(btn1);
        }
```

and with this link button :

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="test"/>
```

it worked, it fired the deleteMeldung method without reloding und passed the parameter meldungId to delete the enterie and updates the new Data to the UpdatePanel

Comment: Good job getting this work. This approach is viable, but in my opinion it has a drawback. In order for the event of the dynamic button to fire, you have to reconstruct all controls (ie the repeater) as they were before the postback. This means either having the repeater use viewstate, or load the data from database on each postback. And then after you process the event, you usually have to bind the repater again to reflect the changes. Not a big deal - but if there is a way of avoiding that, it's probably better imho.